# DRF - Serializing a model with multiple foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, relationship

I am working on a CRUD API in Django and I need to serialize a model which Foreign keys in two tables. The model is on the 'many' side on two one-to-many relationships and I don't really see any other way of specifying relationships in this model(I am new to python and Django and I am using Django-Rest-Framework for creating API)

So, I have two questions:

1 -  `Is it a good Idea to have multiple foreign keys in my model or I should refractor my relationships some other way?`

2 - `If it is fine to have multiple foreign keys in a single model, how do I serialize the model to return the proper JSON?`

My models are something like this(with a few more fields):

```
class DataSource(models.Model):
    datasource_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    datasource_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sender = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    ...

class CampaignDeliveries(models.Model):
    campaign_id = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    datasource_id = models.ForeignKey(DataSource)
    delivery_reference_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField()
```

A delivery record has a reference to the Campaign for which delivery was made and the Data Source which was selected for that delivery.

Data must be returned in a format such as:

```
{
    campaign_id: 001,
    datasource_id: 002,
    datasource_name: "Data Source Name",
    campaign_name: "Campaign Name"
    setup_date:"<Setup Date>",
    delivery_history:[{
        delivery_reference_id:DL_001,
        sender : "abc@xyz.com",
        subject : "Subject",
        sent_on : "<Date>"
    },
    {
        delivery_reference_id:DL_002,
        sender : "abc@xyz.com",
        subject : "Subject",
        sent_on : "<Date>"
    },
    {
        delivery_reference_id:DL_003,
        sender : "abc@xyz.com",
        subject : "Subject",
        sent_on : "<Date>"
    }
    ....
    ]
}
```

The `datasource_id` and `campaign_id` field are the default id given by django to the records while they were created and `delivery_reference_id` is the customized id that was assigned while creating the delivery record.

I hope I have made things clear. However, please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Try this : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: what are you querying to get the data. Can you share the model that populates delivery_history

Comment: What framework do you using for DRF?

Comment: @BipulJain : I am populating delivery history using the following model:      `{
        "campaign_id": 1,
        "datasource_id": 1,
        "delivery_reference_id": "DL_01_01",
        "date_sent": "2017-02-17T00:05:00Z"
    }`      and querrying the data as follows: `/api/campaigns/:campaignID/history/:delivery_reference_id`

Comment: @marin : DRF = Django-Rest-Framework? Didn't quite get your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you name your `ForeignKey` fields like so:

```
class CampaignDelivery(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaign')
```

Field `campaign_id` is added automatically and is a reference to table field which stores id of campaign. I can be useful quite often. So `CampaignDelivery.campaign` returns django object and `CampaignDelivery.campaign_id` returns id of referenced campaign.

There is nothing wrong in having multiple foreign keys in one model but I'm not sure what do you want to accomplish here. I think you ment to get `Campaign` data with its delivery history. 
The response example you provided is not really very good for this as it implies that one delivery can be assigned to multiple campaigns (which is not true because you have `ForeignKey`). You can accomplish this like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CampaignDeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CampaignDelivery
        fields = ('date_sent', 'datasource_id', 'delivery_reference_id', 'datasource__datasource_name', ...)

class CampaignSerializer(serialziers.ModelSerializer):
    delivery_history = CampaignDeliverySerializer(
                           source='campaigndeliveries_set', 
                           many=True
                       )

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'sender', 'subject', 'delivery_history', ...)
```

Example response:

```
{
    'campaign': {
        'id': 123,
        'name': 'Best campaign name evar',
        'sender': 'foo@bar.com',
        'subject': 'Campaign subject',
        'delivery_history': [
            {
                'date_sent': '2017-02-22',
                'datasource_id': 321,
                'delivery_reference_id': 'DL_001',
                'datasource__datasource_name': 'Datasource name'
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: A delivery can have any combination of campaign and data source. Which is why I have two foreign keys.

Comment: Makes more sense with the sample response. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

1) It is your opinion how to FK on models on your own logic, but in this example its my way to do it.

2) Here is answer:

By the default you must name related_name for every FK to the main model.

## models.py

```
class CampaignDeliveries(models.Model):
    delivery_reference_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField()


class DataSource(models.Model):
    datasource_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    datasource_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    campain_id = models.ForeignKey(CampaignDeliveries, related_name='data_source')

class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sender = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    campain_id = models.ForeignKey(CampaignDeliveries, related_name='campaign_source')
```

## serialiers.py

```
class DataSourceSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = DataSource
        fileds = '__all__'


class CampaignSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fileds = '__all__'


class CampaignDeliveriesSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    campaign_source = CampaignSerilaizer(many=True)
    data_source = DataSourceSerilaizer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CampaignDeliveries
        fileds = '__all__'
```

## viwes.py

```
qv = CampaignDeliveries.objects.all()
serializer = CampaignDeliveriesSerilaizer(qv)
print (serializer.data)
```

Comment: NOOOO! You have made the model and serializers the exact opposite of what they should be

Comment: YEAAAAAAA! You can think now in a different way.

Comment: But my data source is not tied down to a single campaign delivery and a single data source may be used in multiple campaign deliveries

Comment: as well as a single campaign may be delivered multiple times using different data sources. So I need to represent the fact that the data source and campaign combinations are delivered and logged into the campaign deliveries table.